# SQL Native Client and network disconnects

Tags: sql-server, network, native-client

Does the SQL Native Client provide support for maintaining a persistent connection over the network at the driver level if there is a momentary network disconnect like a 999 error? Our applications are written in PowerBuilder (versions 12.5 and 6.5) and support SQL Server 2005 - 2014 and Express Edition - Enterprise Edition.

I read about the KeepAlive property at [Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/sql_protocols/understand-special-tcpip-property-keep-alive-in-sql-server-2005) , https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190771(v=sql.120).aspx , and http://www.databaseskill.com/2357386/ . Would this help with this situation?

I also looked at the Microsoft site https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms130822(v=sql.120).aspx which lists all the SQL Native Client connection string properties. I found Failover_Partner, but this is for database mirroring, and I found MultiSubnetFailover, but this is for Always On Availability Groups (AG).

I also looked at http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/.

Thank you!
Mike Petrak

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have `connection pooling` enabled in the connection string for the SQL Server Native Client, then connections are maintained to the SQL Server.

Check [this MSDN blog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/sql_pfe_blog/connection-pooling-for-the-sql-server-dba) for some technical details about how you can confirm if connections are being maintained.

Also, take a look at [this MSDN page for Connection String properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectionstring?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0), and how to ensure connection pooling is enabled.